# ASP.Net Querystring - Multiple values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, request.querystring

Is it possible to pass multiple values to a single Querystring parameter?  Here is what I am thinking:

```
index.aspx?loc=wi&mi&mn
```

or

```
index.aspx=?loc=wi&loc=mi&loc=mn
```

Something like that.  I am sure I could pass them in other ways and possibly explode the inner contents (sorry - split would be better .net term).  But I would rather do this in a way that I could easily extract via code similar to this:

```
for i = 1 to request.querystring("loc").count
    'do some stuff here
next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass multiple values by using a separator between them.

C#

```
var locations = new List<string> { "wi", "mi", "mn" };
var locationsCommaSeparated = string.Join(",", files);
Response.Redirect("index.aspx?loc=" + locationsCommaSeparated);
```

VB

```
Dim locations = New List(Of String)() From { _
    "wi", _
    "mi", _
    "mn" _
}
Dim locationsCommaSeparated = String.Join(",", files)
Response.Redirect("index.aspx?loc=" + locationsCommaSeparated)
```

On the receiving end, you can then split them back out.

C#

```
var locationsCommaSeparated = Request.QueryString["loc"].ToString();
var locations = locationsCommaSeparated.Split(',');

foreach(var location in locations)
{
    //do something
}
```

VB

```
Dim locationsCommaSeparated = Request.QueryString("loc").ToString()
Dim locations = locationsCommaSeparated.Split(","C)

For Each location As var In locations
    'do something
Next
```

Note, I'm a C# programmer, so I used an automatic code converter to convert it to VB. Results may not be idiomatic valid VB.

Careful care would need to be taken if the value you're passing would contain the character you're using as a delimiter. Since it appears you're just passing state abbreviations, you should be safe in this particular instance.

Comment: Thanks again.  I basically just put commas in and exploded out the array of strings, then ran a for-next loop on the array.  Worked out perfectly.  My querystring then become ?loc=wi,mi,mn

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
    ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
    arr.Add(“file1″);
    arr.Add(“file2″);
    arr.Add(“file3″);
    string arry = String.Join(“,”, ((string[])arr.ToArray(typeof(String))));
    Response.Redirect(“index.aspx?file=” + arry);
```

Comment: I'm trying to use and read multiple parameters.  I'm not sure I understand how your code helps that?  Maybe I am missing something, sorry :(

Comment: @Andrew Did you *try* this solution? It's combining multiple values into a comma separated list and so passing multiple parameters in a key/value pair. Exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @Mohammad Why are you using ArrayList and a lot of unnecessary casting? Modern C# uses generic lists. Also, be careful not to use the decorative double quotes `“ ″` in your code, as they aren't valid C#. Use `"` instead.

Comment: I see what you are doing, but I am reading from querystring only. I don't need to generate the querystring.

Comment: @mason You are right.In above example i am using ArrayList because of simplicity. So he can understand easily.

Comment: @Andrew You can split received queryString by using Split(,) function.                        Example = string[] Files = QueryString["file"]..toString().Split(',');

Comment: @MohammadImran But the ArrayList doesn't make it simpler, it makes it harder. You had to do a ToArray call, and you did a completely unnecessary cast to a string array. Do yourself a favor - do not use anything in the System.Collections namespace. Stick to System.Collections.Generic. Also, don't use the decorative double quotes in your post, and when the question asks for an answer in VB, make sure you provide one.

Comment: @mason O. Thanks for your the advice.